# Replacing must when conveying logical deduction

Tags: grammar

Can I use have to/ have got to to replace must when expressing an inference? 
Let's take this sentence for example.

"There must be a catch"

There has to/ there's gotta be a catch.

Comment: Yes. All [periphrastic modals -- _hafta, gonna, wanna, oughta,_ etc)](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+deontic+epistemic+modal+periphrastic) have both epistemic (logical) senses and deontic (permission) senses, just like regular modal auxiliary verbs. This turns out not to be a weird feature of English alone (unlike most topics here), but rather this diglossia is normal for modals in all languages, no matter what their grammar..